# Iterate over reactive form controls

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Basically I want to save all reactive-form values in the session storage and on refresh I want to get the values from session storage to display in the form.

So what I am trying to do is iterate over reactive form controls, and construct an object from those values

That object can be set like `this.form.patchValue(object);`

I want to iterate over each single form control inside my reactive-form and create a structured object.

For Example :

```
profileForm = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(''),
    phoneNo: new FormControl(''),
    selectedService : FormArray('')
    gender:new FormControl(''),
  });
```

In this case `selectedService` is derived from multiple checkboxes. Then I want to create an object like this:

Key & value

```
{
    firstname: "john" 
    phoneNo: "12344567"
    selectedService : {
        service1: true,
        service2: false,
        service3: true
    }
    gender : "male"
}
```

Here's what I tried, but I failed to create a nested object for `formArray`

```
getFormFieldsValue(formControl: any): void {
    Object.keys(formControl.controls).forEach((controlName) => {
      const control = formControl.controls[controlName];
      if (control.controls) {
        this.getFormFieldsValue(control);
      } else {
        this.createObject(controlName, control);
      }
    });
  }

  createObject(controlName: any, controlValue: any): any {
    if (controlValue.value) {
      this.objects[controlName] = controlValue.value;
    }
  }
```

Comment: did you tried console.log(this.profileform.value) ideally the form itself should give you the required object as its value, we design reactive forms in such a way that they return values in the form of the object.

e.g formGroup returns objects, form control returns primitives, formArray returns Array

Comment: @AkshayRajput - see the below answer comments.

Comment: if you need to edit one part of the form you can use the patch if you need to edit complete form you can use set

Comment: Did you try using `form.getRawValues()` ? It is a pretty efficient way to get all the values of all your controls in a given formGroup.

Answer (score 1):

Use `this.profileForm.value` which will give you an object:

```
{
    firstname: "john" 
    phoneNo: "12344567"
    selectedService : [
        true,
        false,
        true
    ]
    gender : "male"
}
```

You'll notice that `selectedService` does not contain the service names, but they are going to be in order, which should work just fine when iterating over the array.

Comment: by patch will it bind checkbox as true/false ? i am using this for multiplecheckbox https://coryrylan.com/blog/creating-a-dynamic-checkbox-list-in-angular

Comment: and also, need to save value to session storage which user enter,  cannot store null value for example : firstname: null

Comment: I don't quite understand but if you are asking, can I patch the value of true/false into the `FormControl`, yes.

Comment: Nothing will ever be `null` because you have `firstName: new FormControl('')` which says "Make a new FormControl with the default value of '' "

Comment: Also, if this answered your question on building an object in preparation for storage in session storage, please accept the answer. If you have questions regarding how to actually get things into session storage or how to populate the form from session storage, please ask a new question.

Comment: well, original question, how to build object with reactive field and reactive field value

Comment: What is `this.profileForm.value` not giving you that you want? It builds an object off of the reactive field value with a given name based on the ones you give in the group. `selectedService` components don't get a name because you are using a `FormArray`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store and get back the values from session storage you should use `JSON.stringify(this.profofileForm.value)`. So you'll get an string than can be stored. Later, you can get back your object with JSON.parse.
To load the values in the form you can initalize them in the FromControl objects:

```
profileForm = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl('this.valFirstName'),
    phoneNo: new FormControl('this.valPhoneNo'),
    selectedService : FormArray('this.SelectedService')
    gender:new FormControl('this.gender'),
  });
```

Where the values valXxxxx come from the parsed json object in the session storage.